# Pointer between two functions in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
int mqtt_connection()
{
    mqtt_broker_handle_t *broker = mqtt_connect(client_name, ip_addr, port);

    if(broker == 0) {  
    printf("Connection failed, Please check the IP and port of broker\n");  
     return 0;          
        }
    else {
        printf("Connection established successfully\n");
    }
    return 1;
}


int publish_mqtt()
{
    char msg[128] = "Test 2";

    if(mqtt_publish(broker, topic1, msg, QoS1) == -1) 
    {
            printf("publish failed\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Sent messages\n");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

I am getting error while building using scons as

```
master.c: In function 'publish_mqtt':
master.c:39:17: error: 'broker' undeclared (first use in this function)
if(mqtt_publish(broker, topic1, msg, QoS1) == -1) 
             ^
master.c:39:17: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once          for each function it appears in
 scons: *** [master.o] Error 1
  scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

How to exchange the value of broker between two functions?. Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: heh? What do you mean? ther's no variable of that name in the second function scope.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `broker` is a local variable in `mqtt_connection` and it hasn't been defined in `publish_mqtt` method

Comment: One way to share variables between two functions is to declare the variable outside the functions.

Comment: broker is mentioned in publish_mqtt() fucntion. But I am not sure why it showing as broker undeclared in mqtt_publish()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to exchange the value of broker between two functions?. Is there any other way to implement this?.

Change the signatures of both functions.

1. Change the first function to return `broker`.
2. Change the second function to expect `broker` as an argument.

---

```
mqtt_broker_handle_t* mqtt_connection()
{
   mqtt_broker_handle_t *broker = mqtt_connect(client_name, ip_addr, port);

   if(broker == 0)
   {
      printf("Connection failed, Please check the IP and port of broker\n");  
      return NULL;          
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Connection established successfully\n");
      return broker;
   }
}


int publish_mqtt(mqtt_broker_handle_t* broker)
{
   char msg[128] = "Test 2";

   if(mqtt_publish(broker, topic1, msg, QoS1) == -1) 
   {
      printf("publish failed\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Sent messages\n");
   }
   return(0);
}
```

---

Change the calling function.

```
mqtt_broker_handle_t* broker = mqtt_connection();
publish_mqtt(broker);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact `broker` is not available in the `publish_mqtt` function due to variable scoping.

Ie: Once the end brace of `mqtt_connection` is hit, broker no longer exists.

```
int mqtt_connection()
{
mqtt_broker_handle_t *broker = mqtt_connect(client_name, ip_addr, port);
...
}
```

If you wish to use it within `publish_mqtt` you need to shift the scope of the variable to be one that covers both functions. Ie:

```
mqtt_broker_handle_t *broker = NULL;

int mqtt_connection()
{
broker = mqtt_connect(client_name, ip_addr, port);
...
}

int publish_mqtt()
{
...
}
```

Comment: I tried your method. I am able to build properly but while executing it gives segmentation fault core dumped error

Comment: If you left the line:

   `mqtt_broker_handle_t *broker = mqtt_connect(client_name, ip_addr, port);`

in `mqtt_connection`, the call to `mqtt_publish(broker, topic1, msg, QoS1)` will now be using a NULL pointer hence the crash.

I've updated the answer showing how to initaize broker correctly